# laravel file manager not showing uploaded image

Tags: laravel, tinymce, laravel-7, file-manager

I am new to laravel file manager and I'm developing a blog using tinymce5 and this package.

Everything works just fine. But...

**The problem:**
The problem is that none of the uploaded images are being shown. neither in file manager "when it's uploaded" nor in the blog.
image is not shown in file manager :

[image]

**What I have done:**
Well the problem is caused by the image url. The url is the url below:

```
http://localhost/storage/photos/maxresdefault.jpg
```

When I changed it to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/photos/maxresdefault.jpg
```

everything worked fine.

**The Question is:**
Is there any way to force laravel file manager to save image urls using "127.0.0.1:8000" instead of "localhost"?
Or is there any way to load images using a more efficient method?

Comment: you should not be saving a full URL, only part of the URI path

Comment: @lagbox exactly, but laravel file manager generates file path by itself. I'm looking for a way to change this "default path generating" behavior.

Comment: that isn't a path that is a URL you are showing ... if it was only using a URI path and using Laravel to generate the URL the host wouldn't be a mismatch .. seems something is specifically saying `localhost`, almost like this package is using `APP_URL` or something

Comment: @lagbox you were right dude :) I changed the APP_URL in .env to 127.0.0.1:8000 and it all worked.

Comment: np, not sure why its using `app.url` configuration value since that is only used from the CLI ... the incoming request to the server is how it knows what host it is ... interesting